# Where to find documentation for hibernate tools

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate-tools

I am trying to find documentation for Hibernate Tools so that I can configure the JPA facet of an Eclipse project to use Hibernate instead of EclipseLink.

Unless I don't know anymore how to do web searches or browse the Eclipse help, the most recent page that I found is https://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.1.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html/index.html, which seems to have been updated in 2011.

Quite strangely, the [Hibernate Tools](http://hibernate.org/tools/) page is the only one (of all listed Hibernate projects) to point to the generic JBoss Tools documentation page, which is definitely not the most helpful of documentation portals.

One year ago, I asked related questions on SO and I remember having met the same difficulties getting some documentation. If someone could help me out, I would appreciate it much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for? http://tools.jboss.org/documentation/howto/hibernate.html

Roughly Steps 4 - 15 detail setting up a new connection which includes a part in step 14 specifically about setting the platform to Hibernate in the `JPA Facet` window:

> 4. In the JPA Facet window, click Add connection.

...

> 13. In the New Connection Profile window, click Finish to return to the JPA Facet window.
> 14. In the Platform list, click Hibernate (JPA 2.1).